# Reinstall Mac OS X without DVD on a new hard drive

Tags: macos, usb, reinstall

I need to reinstall OS X on my MacBook, but the DVD unit is spitting out any DVD I insert into it. Also, the hard disk drive was dead, and I replaced it.

Can you please tell me an alternative to reinstall OS X using a USB memory stick? In Windows I used that alternative from 2009 and I'm very satisfied, but I never installed OS X until now.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your DVD drive is dead, and you don't have a Mac to actually work with.* Therefore, use a Windows PC.

- I believe you can get [TransMac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm) and use its 14-day trial for the following tasks.
- Use it to create a disk image (`.dmg`) from your Snow Leopard DVD. Alternatively, download [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) and create a normal ISO image.
- Again, using TransMac, restore the disk image to the external drive by clicking *Format disk » With disk image*. Alternatively, try to "burn" the ISO to the USB drive using [UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/).
- Unmount the drive from Windows. Attach the external disk to your Mac, hold the `option` key while booting, then install Snow Leopard from it.

<sub>* If you *do* have a Mac, the solution is much easier!</sub>

<sub>This was gathered from [this InsanelyMac](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=203183) and [this MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1122527) post.</sub>