# How to reinstall OS X 10.8 without internet?

Tags: macos, mac, reinstall

I had a crash on my Macbook Air MD231 in Mid 2012 and my system won't boot. Unfortunately my friend erased my partition from disk utility too.

Now I have three question

1. My internet speed is very low. For re-installing, I have to download all of the OS X 10.8 from internet? or I can download it and install it via USB port?(how?)
2. I have to select this option `re-install OS X`? What about size of that? (for example 4.2 GB)
3. After installing, is there anyway to restore my data? Unfortunately I have none of it backed up.

Right now, after I turning my Mac on, it's automatically going to repair mode.

Comment: You can download it then place the data on a disk. When OS X wants the data just point to that location. Here is some additional information: http://superuser.com/questions/381991/reinstall-macos-x-without-dvd-on-a-new-hard-drive?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

It didn't take long to find this: how to create a bootable Flash Drive or DVD to [install Mountain Lion](http://macs.about.com/od/macoperatingsystems/ss/Create-Bootable-Copies-Of-The-Os-X-Mountain-Lion-Installer_4.htm).

You'd need another mac, with mountain lion installer on it.

Comment: thnx, but I just have a PC with windows 8.1!!!!

Comment: @Sam that's fine, but you need a mac. You need to either have one, or borrow time on one, or rent one. PCs do not have the Mac App Store. You may find a sympathetic Apple Store employee that will let you download it there.